# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unable to discover open pages while test execution through InstaPy and selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to run InstaPy on windows based on [this instructions](https://timgrossmann.github.io/InstaPy/How_to_Windows.html)
so I installed it until step 3 and I'm in the advanced setup. because simple set up did'nt work for me.
now i have installed GUI tool from [an .exe setup file](https://github.com/ahmadudin/electron-instaPy-GUI/releases) and running the bot will open a chrome page like this and after a while I get attached error bellow. what should I I do? where did I go wrong?

Im google chrome Version 68.0.3440.75 (Official Build) (64-bit) and currently I use chromedriver.exe version 2.4 and python 3.6.5

first I see this chrome page:
[image]

and after that I see this error in GUI
[image]
the error is this

```
Error: ERROR [2018-07-26 11:16:27] [mohammad.f.rasoulnejad] Message: unknown error: unable to discover open pages
 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.4.226107,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\Mohammad\Desktop\InstaPy\instapy\instapy.py", line 295, in set_selenium_local_session
 chrome_options=chrome_options)
 File "D:\web\Python 3.6.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
 desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
 File "D:\web\Python 3.6.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 90, in __init__
 self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
 File "D:\web\Python 3.6.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 177, in start_session
 response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
 File "D:\web\Python 3.6.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
 self.error_handler.check_response(response)
 File "D:\web\Python 3.6.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
 selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unable to discover open pages
 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.4.226107,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)

 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\Mohammad\Desktop\InstaPy\instapy\instapy.py", line 295, in set_selenium_local_session
 chrome_options=chrome_options)
 File "D:\web\Python 3.6.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
 desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
 File "D:\web\Python 3.6.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 90, in __init__
 self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
 File "D:\web\Python 3.6.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 177, in start_session
 response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
 File "D:\web\Python 3.6.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
 self.error_handler.check_response(response)
 File "D:\web\Python 3.6.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
 selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unable to discover open pages
 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.4.226107,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)


 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "quickstart.py", line 3, in <module>
 session = InstaPy(username='mohammad.f.rasoulnejad', password='myPassword')
 File "C:\Users\Mohammad\Desktop\InstaPy\instapy\instapy.py", line 188, in __init__
 self.set_selenium_local_session()
 File "C:\Users\Mohammad\Desktop\InstaPy\instapy\instapy.py", line 299, in set_selenium_local_session
 Settings.chromedriver_location))
 instapy.instapy.InstaPyError: ensure chromedriver is installed at C:\Users\Mohammad\Desktop\InstaPy\assets\chromedriver
InstaPy ended
```

**UPDATE:**
I downloaded the 2.40 and placed it in assets folder but its 2.4.226107 in the error message
chromedriver=2.4.226107

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12969/devtools/browser/c5a3dd55-34fb-4723-9161-6b8a6e469b29
ERROR [2018-07-26 12:58:34] [mohammad.f.rasoulnejad]  Message: unknown error: unable to discover open pages
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.4.226107,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mohammad\Desktop\InstaPy\instapy\instapy.py", line 295, in set_selenium_local_session
    chrome_options=chrome_options)
  File "D:\web\Python 3.6.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "D:\web\Python 3.6.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "D:\web\Python 3.6.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 177, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "D:\web\Python 3.6.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\web\Python 3.6.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unable to discover open pages
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.4.226107,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mohammad\Desktop\InstaPy\instapy\instapy.py", line 295, in set_selenium_local_session
    chrome_options=chrome_options)
  File "D:\web\Python 3.6.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "D:\web\Python 3.6.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "D:\web\Python 3.6.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 177, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "D:\web\Python 3.6.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\web\Python 3.6.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unable to discover open pages
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.4.226107,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart.py", line 3, in <module>
    session = InstaPy(username='mohammad.f.rasoulnejad', password='myPassword')
  File "C:\Users\Mohammad\Desktop\InstaPy\instapy\instapy.py", line 188, in __init__
    self.set_selenium_local_session()
  File "C:\Users\Mohammad\Desktop\InstaPy\instapy\instapy.py", line 299, in set_selenium_local_session
    Settings.chromedriver_location))
instapy.instapy.InstaPyError: ensure chromedriver is installed at C:\Users\Mohammad\Desktop\InstaPy\assets\chromedriver
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
Message: unknown error: unable to discover open pages
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowsing** session through **Chrome Browser**.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.4*
- ***chromedriver=2.4*** is pretty *old* and *ancient*.
- You are using *Google Chrome Version 68.0.3440.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.40*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.40/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v66-68**

So there is a clear mismatch between the ***ChromeDriver v2.4*** and the ***Chrome Browser v68.0***

---

### Solution

- As you are using **Google Chrome Version 68.0.3440.75** as per the [Release Notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.40/notes.txt) you need to use a compatible *ChromeDriver* binary.
- Download the compatible **ChromeDriver** binary i.e. **ChromeDriver v2.40** (2018-06-07) from [ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).

---

### Update

As you mentioned, even after upgrading to **chromedriver=2.40** you still se the *ChromeDriver* version as **chromedriver=2.4**, you can override the previous version within *OS PATH* by explicitly mentioning the argument `executable_path` as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
```

Comment: I am using 2.4 chromedriver

Comment: @mohammadfallah.rasoulnejad Perhaps _ChromeDriver v2.4_ is pretty **old** and **ancient** and the current GA version is _ChromeDriver v2.40_. Checkout the [Release Notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.40/notes.txt) link within my answer .

Comment: Update the question with your current binary versions along with your _code trials_ and _error stack trace_ for further analysis.

Comment: there is no difference in stack trace than before I think, but updated the question

Comment: If the error message depicts `chromedriver=2.4.226107` which implies that `chromedriver=2.4` is still in effect but nor `chromedriver=2.40`. Can you clear it up?

Comment: where should I change it? I placed the 2.40 in system PATH and removed 2.4 from my computer. Are you sure 2.4 and 2.40 are not the same thing?

Comment: Override the `system PATH` by explicitly mentioning the `executable_path` argument.

Comment: thanks, changed PATH and `chromedriver_location = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets', 'chromedriver')` to `chromedriver_location = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets', 'chromedriver.exe')` in instaPy/settings.py and it works